# Is an application terminated when I close all activities?

Tags: android

I'm using my phone to debug and test my application through android studio. When I hit run on the android studio the application lunches correctly. When I hit the back button on my phone, even though the application seems to close, I don't get an application terminated message on my android studio run log and the red stop  button  on anroid studio is still clickable. The application is just an empty test application.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
}
```

The same thing happens if I use finish() to terminate the application through code. I would like to know if this is normal behavior for an android application or if I'm doing something wrong. Why does the android studio process remain on? Has my app terminated properly or am I leaving unterminated applications on the memory this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I hit the back button on my phone, even though the application seems to close, I don't get an application terminated message on my android studio run log and the red stop button on anroid studio is still clickable

I do not know what "an application terminated message" means. Pressing BACK will destroy an activity (by default). It has no immediate effect on your process, which is what the red stop button in Android Studio is tied to.

> I would like to know if this is normal behavior for an android application or if I'm doing something wrong

This is normal behavior.

> Why does the android studio process remain on?

The red stop button is enabled because the process is still running. Android will terminate the process when Android decides to do so, usually because it is running low on system RAM.

> am I leaving unterminated applications on the memory this way?

Yes. This is by design. The user might elect to return to your app fairly quickly, in which case it is more efficient to just start a fresh activity in your existing process than would be to start a process, then start an activity in that process.

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal behaviour.

As Android system manages background tasks on it's own when you exit your app by pressing back button, your app's process is is still running in background in case you might need to get back to it. But if you do not get back to your app it's instance is destroyed by the OS after some time.

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal behaviour on Android Studio!